# Error on radio buttons?

Tags: coldfusion

Getting error

```
Context validation error for tag cfinput.  
The tag must be nested inside a cfform tag.
```

But I do have the form tag around the cfinput.
What could be causing the error?

Side note: before it use to be a select , but I would like to change it to a radio button.

```
<form method="post" action="cse_allusers_addcomment.cfm" name="add_comment">
        <cfoutput>
            <input type="hidden" name="txtSubmitter" value="#GetCurrentUser.emp_id#">
            ..more code...
        </cfoutput>
        <table>
        <thead>
        ......
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <cfoutput>
           <cfloop index="i" from="1" to="5">
                 <cfset question = GetEmployeeCSEDepts["csedept_question" & i][GetEmployeeCSEDepts.CurrentRow]>
                   <cfif question neq "">

                       <tr>
                           <td valign="top">
                                        <cfinput type="radio" name="ratingradio" value="5">Exceptional<br>
                                        <cfinput type="radio" name="ratingradio" value="4">Exceeds Standards<br>
                                        <cfinput type="radio" name="ratingradio" value="3">Successful<br>
                                        <cfinput type="radio" name="ratingradio" value="2">Needs Improvement<br>
                                        <cfinput type="radio" name="ratingradio" value="1">Unsatisfactory<br>
                                        <cfinput type="radio" name="ratingradio" value="0">N/A<br>


                                  </td>
                         <td valign="top">#question#</td>
                     </tr>
                  </cfif>
                </cfloop>
            </cfoutput>
        </tbody>
        </table>

        <cfoutput>
        <p>
        <br>
        <textarea style="width:99%;" rows="3" name="txtPosComment"></textarea></p>
        </cfoutput>
        <p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></p> 

    </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have it nested in a `<form>` tag but `<cfinput>` is expecting/requiring to be nested within a `<cfform>` tag.

By the way, why are you using `<cfinput>` tags anyway? You do not need to in the example given. Just use normal HTML `<form>` and `<input>` tags.

Comment: just got it here http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=formatData_02.html

Comment: cant believe i miss that

Comment: Ha! It happens. But remember, from the code you posted here using `cfinput` is not necessary. Using the `cf` form stuff adds a lot of javascript to your pages and if you aren't using it there is no need for it. Just use standard HTML `input` tags.

Comment: thanks i change it to <input>, but would you know since each show a the radio buttons for each question , why i cant choose more than one button?

Comment: Because they all have the same value for the name attribute. You'll need to create a unique name for the inputs each pass through the loop.

Comment: By design radio buttons are meant to only allow one choice. If you want to allow multiple then use checkbox. Or use unique names as Carl mentioned.